# Get Segment/Polyline id from maps

Tags: google-maps, here-api

Hi i try to find if the google maps or the HERE nokia maps have a static segmentation of the roads and an associated id and where i can find this information. I try to rich information by Rest api from both maps type but i don't find it. Instead with the javascript api i see that i can edit the maps or create, but what i want is to query a server or a database's maps in the way that i can use the latitude and longitude information as key for research (or the address string) and i will get the information from where is the location (so address or lat/long) and in what segment/polyline of the street the location is.
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to look at a RESTful API rather than JavaScript:

For the HERE Platform:

- To get an address for a Lat/Lng or vice-versa use the [Geocoder API](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder)
- To get an road shapes for a Lat/Lng use the [Enterprise Routing API](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-routing)

You will need to register to get access to the documentation, but you can see the APIs in action using the API Explorer e.g. [Geocoder](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/api-explorer#geocoder) [Routing](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/enterprise-api-explorer#routing)

The `getlinkinfo` endpoint of the Enterprise Routing API could be useful. For example, the URL below ( replace YOUR_APP_ID and YOUR_TOKEN of course)

http://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/getlinkinfo.json?app_idYOUR_APP_ID&app_code=YOUR_APP_CODEg&waypoint=52.53086,13.3846&linkattributes=shape

Returns the following link info about a line segment:

```
{
    "Response":
    {
        "MetaInfo":
        {
            "MapVersion":"2013Q2",
            "ModuleVersion":"0.2",
            "InterfaceVersion":"4.2",
            "Timestamp":"2013-12-12T12:45:47.035Z"
        },
        "Link":[
            {
                "_type":"PrivateTransportLinkType",
                "LinkId":"+931447247",
                "Shape":[
                    "52.5309486,13.38447",
                    "52.5310516,13.38482"
                ],
                "SpeedLimit":13.89,
                "DynamicSpeedInfo":
                {
                    "TrafficSpeed":6.94,
                    "TrafficTime":3.7,
                    "BaseSpeed":13.89,
                    "BaseTime":1.9
                },
                "Address":
                {
                    "Label":"Invalidenstraße",
                    "Country":"DE",
                    "State":"Berlin",
                    "County":"Berlin",
                    "City":"Berlin",
                    "District":"Mitte",
                    "Street":"Invalidenstraße"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```